# How to add the VAT on the selected products in Commerce Kickstart?

Tags: commerce

I am using Drupal commerce kickstart. Can anyone tell me how to create the field for the VAT in the product creation form? I need a field for each product listed in the product form.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module [Commerce VAT](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_vat) for this purpose

> Commerce VAT module is an improved module for supporting VAT than the
>   Commerce Tax module included in Commerce. If you are using Commerce
>   VAT is is recommended you disable Commerce Tax.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is calculate the VAT based on the price and not add it as a field.  There is the [Commerce VAT](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_vat) module, which is a specialised module just for VAT calculations.

This module will add the VAT to the order as a line item at checkout.

Comment: If I have to add different VAT on two or more products then how to do that.

Please Tell me

Thanks for help

Comment: You mean different rates of VAT?

Comment: Can you tell me how can i use the Commerce VAT module.